# Changing marker sizes in matplotlib's legend when using tuples for markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a plot as following

```
    from numpy.random import randn
    m=np.random.uniform(size=10)
    x=np.arange(0,10,1)
    y=x**2
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    
    blue_dot = ax.scatter(x[:5],y[:5], s=m[:5]*100, color='b')

    red_dot = ax.scatter(x[5:],y[5:], s=200*m[5:], color='r')
    black_cross = ax.scatter(x[5:],y[5:], s=400*m[5:], marker='+', color='k')
    
    lgnd = ax.legend([blue_dot, (red_dot, black_cross)], ["Blue Circle", "Red Circle and Black Cross"])
```

[image]

Note: In the above plot, I can't seem to figure out on what factors is the markersize in legend dependent since I anyway have multiple markersizes in the plot.

Now I want to change the size of the markers in the legend so that all the markers are of equal size. For that, I have tried adding this to the above code.

```
lgnd.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [200]
lgnd.legendHandles[1]._sizes = [200] # this is affecting the size of red_dot only
```

[image]

How do I change the size of `black_cross` as well in the legend, so it is proportional to the `red_dot`? As you can see, the `black_cross` is twice the size of `red_dot` as given by the `s` parameter in `ax.scatter` function.

Comment: What do you mean by saying *change the size of the markers in the legend so that all the markers of equal size*? If you want all the markers in the plot to be the same size, remove `s` argument in each `ax.scatter()`.

Comment: I have edited the description now. I initially missed typing a word.
Since I am using a tuple of markers, I am able to only change the size of the first item of the tuple(red_dot). All I want to do is to be able to change the size of all the items of the tuple(in this case, black_cross).

Comment: Regarding removing the `s` argument; I want the markers to be of the same size only in legend and also note that I don't have any control of the marker size in legend in the first plot. I can't seem to figure out on what factors it is dependent as I have multiple maker sizes in the plot.

Comment: If you align all the marker sizes to `s=200*[5:]` the same standard of 200, the size of the precedent will be the same size. The size of the markers is controlled by `m`, so I don't think it's a problem. I confirmed this by increasing the graph size in my environment.

Comment: From your comment,  I have realized my mistake of not using slice of m for sizes and made the correction, but that still doesn't answer my question which is "How do I change the size of `black_cross` as I did to `red_dot` by using `lgnd.legendHandles[1]._sizes`"

Comment: The point of the previous comment was not to slice, but to multiply the size of the blue circle, the red circle, and the black cross by a specified range of 200, so that the legend is also aligned.